# How do I create a categorical bar chart using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a bar chart such that the x-axis contains the different `engine_type` and the y-axis contains the `count`. Data frame (DEU_2001_df) below:

```
   Year engine_type                count
1  2001 petrol_number           2185247 
2  2001 diesel_gas_number       1155300 
3  2001 full_mild_hybrid_number     606.
4  2001 plugin_hybrid_number          0 
5  2001 battery_electric_number      56
```

When using the following line:

```
ggplot(DEU_2001_df, mapping = aes(x = 'engine_type', y = 'count')) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I get this plot:
[image]

Steps taken as above.

Comment: ggplot expects unquoted column names inside `aes`. Change to `aes(x = engine_type, y = count))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your `count` values it will be hard to see `battery_electric_number`, `full_mild_hybrid_number`.
Here is suggestion using the log of `count`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(count = as.numeric(count)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(engine_type, count), y = log(count)))+
  geom_col(fill = "maroon") +
  labs(title = "log of count", x = "Engine type") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use variable name without inverted commas:

`engine %>% ggplot(aes(x = engine_type, y = count)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`